# MonthNavigation buttons color in Material3 DatePicker

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

I'm unable to change color of month navigation buttons in jetpack compose DatePicker:

[image]

Tried modifying theme colors and managed to change the color of everything except the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Material3` `DatePicker` you can change color using `selectedDayContainerColor` and set your desired color.

```
Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
       
        val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState(initialSelectedDateMillis = 1578096000000)
        DatePicker(state = datePickerState, modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
            colors = DatePickerDefaults.colors(
                navigationContentColor = Color.Red
            ))

        Text("Selected date timestamp: ${datePickerState.selectedDateMillis ?: "no selection"}")
    }
```

You can change the whole horizontal container colour using the above code there is no option for change color only for **MenuButton**

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Can you please double check if you showed me DatePicker from Material3 and if it has "navigationContentColor" in its DatePickerDefaults? because right now I don's see colors parameter. i have colorScheme. also can you please show me your Material3 gradle version?

Comment: I'm currently using this version ```implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha06")```

Comment: worked like a charm!